# Correcting logic on a return option on a loop python 3.6

Tags: python-3.x, loops

I was taking a online class for Python and one of the tutorials is to create a battle system for a RPG. I finished the tutorial and felt that there was so much missing. One of the missing features was there is no option to go back to a players action which can lead to an infinite loop. I have coded a large section to include a way to go back by typing '0' and it works except for when there is no quantity for an item when selecting items and when there is no more MP for a spell. What happens in that case is when '0' is selected, the last entry on the array is automatically implemented. So lets say I have no MP and 'cura' is my last spell on the list, if I select '0' cura gets cased regardless. Can anyone tak a look at this small section I have included to see where the error is? I will include the entire code if needed.

```
while running:
print("====================\n")
print("NAME               HP                                       MP")

for player in players:
    player.get_stats()

print("")

for enemy in enemies:
    enemy.get_enemy_stats()

for player in players:
    # check if player won
    if defeated_enemies == 3:
        print("\n" + bcolors.OKGREEN + "You Win!\n♫♫ Fanfare ♫♫" + bcolors.ENDC)
        running = False
        break

    start = True

    while start:
        start = False
        choice = player.choose_action()
        index = choice - 1

        if index == 0:
            dmg = player.generate_damage()
            enemy = player.choose_target(enemies)

            enemies[enemy].take_damage(dmg)
            print("\n" + player.name.replace(" ", "") + " attacked " + enemies[enemy].name.replace(" ", "") + " for", dmg, "points of damage.")

            if enemies[enemy].get_hp() == 0:
                print(bcolors.BOLD + bcolors.FAIL + enemies[enemy].name.replace(" ", "") + " HAS FALLEN!" + bcolors.ENDC)
                del enemies[enemy]
                defeated_enemies += 1

        elif index == 1:
            check_mp = True
            while check_mp:
                mag_choice = player.choose_magic()
                magic_choice = mag_choice - 1
                spell = player.magic[magic_choice]
                magic_dmg = spell.generate_damage()
                current_mp = player.get_mp()

                if spell.cost > current_mp:
                    print(bcolors.FAIL + "\nNot enough MP. Please choose a different spell. Type 0 to go back." + bcolors.ENDC)
                    continue
                else:
                    check_mp  = False

            if magic_choice == -1:
                start = True
                continue

            player.reduce_mp(spell.cost)

            if spell.type == "white":
                player.heal(magic_dmg)
                print(bcolors.OKBLUE + "\n" + spell.name + " heals", player.name, "for", str(magic_dmg), "HP." + bcolors.ENDC)
                if player.hp > player.maxhp:
                   player.hp = player.maxhp

            elif spell.type == "black":
                enemy = player.choose_target(enemies)
                enemies[enemy].take_damage(magic_dmg)
                print(bcolors.OKBLUE + "\n" + spell.name + " deals", str(magic_dmg), "points of damage to " + enemies[enemy].name.replace(" ", "") + bcolors.ENDC)

                if enemies[enemy].get_hp() == 0:
                    print(bcolors.BOLD + bcolors.FAIL + enemies[enemy].name.replace(" ", "") + " HAS FALLEN!" + bcolors.ENDC)
                    del enemies[enemy]
                    defeated_enemies += 1

        elif index == 2:
            choose_item = True
            while choose_item:
                itm_choice = player.choose_item()
                item_choice = itm_choice -1
                item = player.items[item_choice]["item"]

                if player.items[item_choice]["quantity"] == 0:
                    print(bcolors.FAIL + "\nThere are no more " + str(item.name) +"s left. Please choose a different item. Type 0 to go back." + bcolors.ENDC)
                    continue
                else:
                    break

            if item_choice == -1:
                start = True
                continue

            player.items[item_choice]["quantity"] -= 1

            if item.type == "potion":
                player.heal(item.prop)
                print(bcolors.OKGREEN + "\n" + item.name + " heals", player.name, "for", str(item.prop), "HP." + bcolors.ENDC)
                if player.hp > player.maxhp:
                   player.hp = player.maxhp

            elif item.type == "elixer":
                if item.name == "MegaElixer":
                    print("\n" + player.name.replace(" ", ""), "uses", item.name)
                    print(bcolors.OKGREEN + "HP and MP fully restored to all party members!" + bcolors.ENDC)
                    for i in players:
                        i.hp = i.maxhp
                        i.mp = i.maxmp
                else:
                    player.hp = player.maxhp
                    player.mp = player.maxmp
                    print(player.name.replace(" ", ""), "uses", item.name)
                    print(bcolors.OKGREEN + player.name.replace(" ", "") + " HP and MP fully restored!" + bcolors.ENDC)

            elif item.type == "attack":
                enemy = player.choose_target(enemies)
                enemies[enemy].take_damage(item.prop)
                print(bcolors.FAIL + "\n" + item.name + " deals", str(item.prop), "points of damage to " +  enemies[enemy].name.replace(" ", "") + bcolors.ENDC)

                if enemies[enemy].get_hp() == 0:
                    print(bcolors.BOLD + bcolors.FAIL + enemies[enemy].name.replace(" ", "") + " HAS FALLEN!" + bcolors.ENDC)
                    del enemies[enemy]
                    defeated_enemies += 1
    else:
        continue
```